# Caffe Deep learning framework convert Normalize to BatchNorm

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am using TIDL (TI Deep learning library) to convert deep learning models to be used in embedded systems.
The version I use does not support Caffe's "Normalize" layer, so I would like to somehow use "BatchNorm" instead. Is something like this is possible by directly editing prototxt files? If so, how can I modify Normalize into a BatchNorm, as they take different parameters.

Any help is greately appreciated. Thank you.

```
...
    layer {
      name: "conv10_2_relu"
      type: "ReLU"
      bottom: "conv10_2"
      top: "conv10_2"
    }
    layer {
      name: "conv4_3_norm"
      type: Normalize
      bottom: "conv4_3"
      top: "conv4_3_norm"
      norm_param {
        across_spatial: false
        scale_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 20
        }
        channel_shared: false
      }
    }
    layer {
      name: "conv4_3_norm_mbox_loc"
      type: "Convolution"
      bottom: "conv4_3_norm"
      top: "conv4_3_norm_mbox_loc"
      param {
        lr_mult: 1
        decay_mult: 1
      }
      param {
        lr_mult: 2
        decay_mult: 0
      }
      convolution_param {
        num_output: 16
        pad: 1
        kernel_size: 3
        stride: 1
        weight_filler {
          type: "xavier"
        }
        bias_filler {
          type: "constant"
          value: 0
        }
      }
    }
...
```